# Is it possible to compile a react-native app for android with an offline pc

Tags: react-native

Upon trying my first react-native android app with a win 10 pc, after entering the command `react-native run-android`, the compiler downloads a lot of files `gradle-**-all` and some `*.pom` files before finally deploying the app. i'm in a country with expensive data bundles so i want to ask:

Does this happen for every project, or every compile ?
If yes, are there workarounds ?
Because i need to be able to develop apps while offline.

Comment: Your likely option is to connect a physical device via USB and run android. The first time it may need Internet connection to compile etc... But then you good to go

Comment: do i need the internet connection for every project's compile ? i.e are the files downloaded and stored for each project locally or are they global? i need this information to weigh my options. Thank you.

Comment: Once you `run-android` via USB you will get an .apk application on your device, then you can run it whenever you connect via USB without any internet. I haven't tried it with multiple projects. So I do not know if you have to do a 'first time' compile for each project. But you can try it and let us know. Also, I highly suggest you download all packages you will be needing for the project before doing the first time compile.